# Please help me to anwser (V)

Tags: logic, proof-writing, formal-proofs

The functions f(n) and g(n) are deﬁned for positive integers n as follows:
f(n) = 2n + 1, g(n) = 4n.
This question is about the set S of positive integers that can be achieved by applying, in some order, a combination of fs and gs to the number 1. For example as
gfg(1) = gf(4) = g(9) = 36,
and
ffgg(1) = ffg(4) = ff(16) = f(33) = 67,
then both 36 and 67 are in S.

(i) Write out the binary expansion of 100 (one hundred).

(ii) Show that 100 is in S by describing explicitly a combination of fs and gs that achieves 100.

(iii) Show that 200 is not in S.

(iv) Show that, if n is in S, then there is only one combination of applying fs and gs in order to achieve n. (So, for example, 67 can only be achieved by applying g then g then f then f in that order.)

(v) Let $u_k $ be the number of elements  n of   S that lie in the range $ 2^k<n < 2^{k+1} $

Show that
$$u_{k+2} = u_{k+1} + u_{k}$$
Please help me to anwser (V)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Even when you are stuck @ 5 , you should show your efforts on 1,2,3,4. Here , 5 will Directly come out when you go via 1,2,3,4 which are actually hints. To start you off , 100 Decimal is 64+32+4 hence it is 1100100 in Binary.

Comment: I know how to get 1,2,3,4,but can't get 5

Comment: Include that effort in your Post , we can see what next !